# How to add a column of Float64 all filled with NA values to a Julia DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Seems silly, but I can't figure out how to add a column of Float64 all filled with NA values to a Julia DataFrame in a simple way.

I can do it with the following code, but it seems odd:

```
df = DataFrame(col1 = [1,2,3], col2 = ['a','b','c'])

df[:a] = 1:size(df, 1)
df[:a] = convert(DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1},df[:a])
[df[i,:a] = NA  for i in 1:size(df, 1) ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataArrays are intialized with `NA`s by default.

So you should just be able to do:

```
df = DataFrame(col1 = [1,2,3], col2 = ['a','b','c'])

df[:a] = DataArray(Float64,size(df,1))
```